# Android get audio output

Tags: java, android, audio

Is it possible to get the raw audio being played by the other apps? My idea is to create a visualizer like you find in iTunes or windows media player that will work with any app. I've looked around but haven't seen anything that would work. If anyone could point me in the right direction, I would really appreciated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might access the buffers via JNi and C++..